# Finding Child Form of a given application

Tags: c#

I am looking to create an application to help my gf with emulators (launching and manage the game input profiles) because she is not good with a computer. What i am trying to do is to launch the emulator then with the mouse to move to the right places to configure the emulator then start the game, that part is good but I can't find a way to get the handle of the child form that shows when I get to configure the emulator.

First I get the emulator location on the screen from the process name then the function GetWindowRect
Second I move the window to a given location on the screen and from there each emulator input settings is at a different location so I hard code mouse movements to launch the settings form but from there i can't find a way to get the location of that child form from the handle of the main form.

[[Emulator settings screenshot]:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yd9l.png)

```
//this part is in the window form .cs file
if(path != "Exe not found"){ //can be C:\location\Dolphin\dolphin.exe if the path is found
    Process proc = Process.Start(path);
    while(string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle)){
        Thread.Sleep(25);
        proc.Refresh();
    }
    Activate();
    MouseControl.control("dolphin", lstEmuGames.SelectedIndex);
}

//this code is in the mouse_movement.cs
public void control(string emuName, int lstIndex = 0){
    MessageBox.Show("DO NOT MOVE THE MOUSE UNTIL THE GAME STARTS");
    ControlForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Process proc = getProcess(emuName);//ex dolphin.exe
    if(proc != null){
    Rect pos = getPos(proc.MainWindowHandle);
        //gets the position of the emulator main form
        if(pos.Left > -1){
            moveTo(pos.Left + ((pos.Right - pos.Left) / 2), pos.Top + 10);
            dragNDrop((pos.Right - pos.Left) / 2 + 25, 25);

/*this part gets the emulator<s main form to pixel 25,25 of the main screen then
from here i dont know what to do to get the child form (Dolphin controller config)  
location to hard code the buttons and other controls exact location*/

        }
}
private Process getProcess(string emuName){
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach(Process process in processList)
        if(process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(emuName)) return process;
    return null;
}
private Rect getPos(IntPtr processHandle){
    Rect pos = new Rect();
    pos.Left = -1;
    GetWindowRect(processHandle, ref pos);
    return pos;
}
```

use the getPos function to return the child form location to allow me to move the mouse accordingly to the window location

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have you thought about using automation tools that are geared specifically towards usage scenarios such as yours (like AutoHotKey or AutoIt)? Choosing C# to attempt scripting/automating the UI of a third application is like choosing the hard and painful way compared to using (GUI) automation tools...

Comment: @Grez also, are you sure the emulator does not support command line configuration / config files per game>?  I would research that option first.

Comment: @elgonzo I never used AutoHotKey or Autolt so I didn't knew they existed and I chose C# to build a Windows Form with listboxes to list all games and emulators on the PC in a specific folder then select if I want to connect 1,2, 3 or 4 controllers and config them with automatisation

Comment: @PaulThomas some of them have settings.xml files but it's not that i want to change the video settings or other... just the controllers to be sure that it is the right profile selected